# Best mobile development language for OMR?

Tags: mobile, omr

I want to make app like [zipgrade](https://www.zipgrade.com/) for my school project. This app works with server but i want to make it works locally. I found some apps about OMR written by python. I found a framework kivy for making android app but this framework has bad frontend contents. I want to make it with good frontend. Which language is best for making app like i said? My first priority for this project, it needs to work locally. Thanks for advices.